# I get permission denied error while trying to run bundle install

Tags: ruby, macos, bundler

I recently switched from Linux to Mac, and while trying to run bundle on one of my previous projects, I get the error below:

```
System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `read': Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/specifications/puma-2.14.0.gemspec (Errno::EACCES)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:959:in `load'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:644:in `block (2 levels) in each_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:643:in `block in each_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:642:in `each_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:658:in `each_normal'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:669:in `_all'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:822:in `each'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `find_all'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:253:in `matching_specs'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:277:in `to_specs'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in `to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'
```

I have tried reinstalling `bundler`, `rbenv` and `ruby`, but I keep getting the same error. I ran the command with `sudo` and it works, how can I set the permission without having to use `sudo`

Comment: Are you sure it's the same error when you run with `sudo`? It's not some other stacktrace?

Comment: I retried with `sudo` now and it works. How can U make it work without `sudo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I retried with sudo now and it works. How can U make it work without sudo

To make bundler work without sudo, you should install all your gem dependencies in a local user directory (this is the recommended way)

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Now when you run your program, bundle will find all your libraries in the new location

```
bundle exec ruby app.rb
```

If you are using git, make sure to add `vendor` to your `.gitignore` to avoid having all your gem libraries in your "new files" list.

Comment: I also have the same problem, but when I tried "bundle install --path vendor/bundle" command to execute I got this error "-bash: bundle: command not found"